# jquery ajax character encoding for json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, utf-8, character-encoding

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'js/questions.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        encoding: 'UTF-8'
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    })  
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        do_sliding(false, '#start', false, true);
    });
```

The **questions.json** file looks like this:

```
    {
        "questions": [
            {
                "question":"Er du forpliktet til å lese \"Code of conduct\"-dokumentet?",
                "choice_1":"Alle nyansatte skal lese det, men ikke de som har jobbet i Infratek i over to år",
                "choice_2":"Bare ledere med personalansvar",
                "choice_3":"Alle ansatte",
                "answer":"3"
            },
            {
                "question":"Hvor ofte må man lese igjennom \"Code of Conduct\"?",
                "choice_1":"Når man blir ansatt, deretter ved endringer",
                "choice_2":"En gang i året i forbindelse med Energisamtalen",
                "choice_3":"Det er tilstrekkelig å lese en gang, deretter er det sjefens ansvar å informere om endringer",
                "answer":"2"
            }
     ]
}
```

As you can see i have some regional characters like: åøåæ and so on. But these characters are not encoded properly. I get this kinda things: �. Character encoding also set in my html page `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: Are you sure all the files in motion are set as UTF8 ?

Comment: Actually that was the problem which I found later. But thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a JSON file. On the javascript side of the communication, there is no file but an answer to a request. I assume you have a file on your server that you post on the request or the request generates this data.

In either way it depends on your server if it is able and configured to convert some character encoding to UTF-8.

Also when the server reads the json data from a file or somewhere else it might not know anything about the encoding of the file. If you ask me, a sane server lives in a system that uses UTF-8 by default.

So it's likely that your server delivers the JSON file without recoding and the file is not encoded as UTF-8 which will result in broken characters.

If it is a static file you can simply convert it, for example with

```
iconv -f WHATEVER_CODEPAGE_YOU_USE -t utf8 <original.json>uf8.json
```

.